# Limit as n -> ∞ for RSolve with Multivariate Recurrence Relation

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I'm trying to solve the following when `n -> ∞`:

```
RSolve[{
   a[n + 1] == a[n] + x (1 - a[n] - b[n]),
   b[n + 1] == b[n] + y (1 - a[n] - b[n]),
   a[0] == 0, b[0] == 0},
   {a[n], b[n]}, n]
```

After a FullSimplify, I get the following for `a[n]` (and similarly for `b[n]`):
[image: http://i.imgur.com/gIGir7a.png]

It's clear that as `n` gets larger that this expression converges so long as `0 < x < 1` and `0 < y < 1`, but simply plugging in `n = ∞` I get "Sum does not converge" as an error. For instance when I set `n = 20` and `x = 1/3` and `y = 1/4` I get the following:

```
547679985297149068793/
958439998111868780544
```

For `n = 50`:

```
130006259285744996749134383652034872751260675268341857/
227510953750053744333189631883564158123178815081414656
```

In floating point notation these both are ~0.571429, which is approximately 4/7 (thanks @hftf), suggesting the answer is `(1/y)(1/x + 1/y)`. How does one get RSolve to return this result?

Comment: You mean, `4/7`?

Comment: Did you do the simplification with assumptions on x,y, or (especially) n? If not, that could help.

Comment: @hftf ...yes, haha. So I guess the answer is just `(1/y)/(1/y + 1/x)` for a[n]? But how to find that from RSolve...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried, but the two Sums remain, regardless of the assumptions. The best I was able to do is get rid of the `UnitStep[n-1]` from the numerators when assuming `n >= 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the unsimplified `UnitStep` nonsense in Mathematica’s result. For example, the expression
`(1 - x - y)^K[1] UnitStep[-1 + K[1]] + UnitStep[-K[1]]` really just ought to be `(1 - x - y)^K[1]` instead. So let’s write a `unitStepSimplify` function to simplify expressions containing that, and apply it:

```
unitStepSimplify = # /. {UnitStep[-i_] + f_ UnitStep[i_ - 1] -> f} &;

closedForms = RSolve[{
    a[n + 1] == a[n] + x (1 - a[n] - b[n]), 
    b[n + 1] == b[n] + y (1 - a[n] - b[n]),
    a[0] == 0, b[0] == 0}, {a[n], b[n]}, n];

simplifiedClosedForms = 
  FullSimplify[closedForms // unitStepSimplify, 
    Assumptions -> n >= 1]
```

> ```
> {{a[n] -> (x - x (1 - x - y)^n)/(x + y), 
>   b[n] -> (y - (1 - x - y)^n y)/(x + y)}}
> ```

Nice. To find the `n → ∞` limit:

```
% /. (f_ -> r_ ) :> (f -> Limit[r, n -> ∞, Assumptions :> {0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}]
```

> ```
> {{a[n] -> x/(x + y), b[n] -> y/(x + y)}}
> ```

There you go:

$$a(n)=\frac x{x+y}\qquad\qquad b(n)=\frac y{x+y}$$